# VBA "like" does not what it is supposed to do

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a list of about 2500 rows and I want to check wheter or not in the first column the words "intern" followed by ":" appear (the : can be at any position after intern) in a loop

The important part of the code looks like this:

```
For k = 1 To lastrowND
intern = Worksheets("new Data").Cells(k, 1).Value


If Not intern Like "*intern*:" Then
```

However this command does not filter anything. Where is my mistake?

Thank you very much

Comment: I would guess it fails due to the : at the end.

Comment: Have you confirmed (via a breakpoint) that any of the Value's are actually populated with the pattern you're searching for?  Do other (more basic) patterns work as expected?

Comment: Yeah I had the code working when it only looked for "intern", but I need the additional condition that a ":" comes after it anywhere in the string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your data has anything after the colon, then you will need an additional `*` for it to test true. ( `*intern*:*` )

The regex sort of defaults to assuming you want leading and trailing wildcards. Regular expressions can be insanely powerful though, so it is worth taking some time to play with them if you have the time.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use the regular expressions like this:

```
Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = "intern(.*?):"
Dim regEx As New RegExp

' ...

With regEx
     .Global = True
     .IgnoreCase = False
     .Pattern = strPattern
End With

For k = 1 To lastrowND
   intern = Worksheets("new Data").Cells(k, 1).Value

   If Not regEx.Test(intern) Then
   ' ...
```

Comment: This looks very promising but I have never worked with this function. How exactly do I integrate the loop [Worksheets("new Data").Cells(k, 1).Value] with this command? thx anyways

Comment: Mario, you don't need to change anything in the loop! Just define out of the loop the Dim regEx As New RegExp and use "If Not regEx.Test(intern ) Then" instead of "If Not intern Like "*intern*:" Then". I have also edited my answer, please take a look.

Comment: Thx for your edit of the code. However I cant complie code pointing to the line        Dim regEx As New RegExp

Comment: Probably only missing some dependencies. Go to Tools -> References -> Find & check the "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions"

Comment: Thx for your help dude. Yorik gave the right pointer in the comment above, instead of "*intern*:" I needed to add another * at the end as the string usually never ended in :.